# Background-Images in Buttons for IB cause layout issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am having an issue with this calculator that I am working on, where the layout of the UI dislikes the current constraints, and will remove the UILabels from view (Apologies for lack of image).

The constraints applied for this 5x5 grid include (Where background images are [UIButton Elements]):

- 8px margin on all sides
- Equal width and height

The constraints applied to the labels:

- Set margin on lead, top, and trail.
- Set vertical distance in between labels

Notes about Grid: The grid is touching the bottom-most blue-alignment line for the bottom label.

Text based layout:

```
=====
=====
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Where ===== is a UILabel
Where . is a UIButton (With background)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What issues? Unclear what you are asking

Comment: I don't know whether this may happen or not, but maybe your labels get a height of 0 at initial layout when they might be empty. You might want to set a specific height to the labels.

Comment: Fixed it, it turns out that the labels had a lower compression priority, which allowed the buttons to push them out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

In the size inspector, increase the priority of compression for the labels. That will fix the moderate priority errors, and correct the location of the elements.